# Replace symbolic link which linked to directory target

Tags: directory, symlink

I want to upgrade tomcat server from 7.0.19 to 7.0.20.

I've already `ln -s apache-tomcat-7.0.19 tomcat7` before, so now I need to *link* `tomcat7` to new target using the following command `ln -s --force apache-tomcat-7.0.21 tomcat7`, but it does not worked as what I expected: it created a symbolic link `tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.21` instead of replace existing `tomcat7` symbolic link with new target.

**Example**

```
# mkdir v1 v2
# ln -s v1 v
# ln -s v2 v
# ll v*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    2 Sep  5 16:02 v -> v1

v1:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 2 Sep  5 16:02 v2 -> v2

v2:
total 0
```

I checked the [manual of `ln`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln), I think `ln -s --force apache-tomcat-7.0.21 tomcat7` use the 3rd form instead of 1st form to explain the parameters. That's so ambiguous between the 1st and 3rd form. So how to replace symbolic link in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want the `-T` option:

```
$ mkdir v1
$ ln -s v1 foo
$ ls -FlA | grep foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 phil phil     2 2011-09-05 01:58 foo -> v1/
$ mkdir v2
$ ln -s -T -f v2 foo
$ ls -FlA | grep foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 phil phil     2 2011-09-05 01:59 foo -> v2/
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. What a shame, I see this *optional* option in help, but I don't know what it exactly does.

Answer (score 21):

While replacing symbolic links to directories we should use `-n` option.

Example: `ln -sfn /path/to/directory /target/directory`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Solves the question and one-liner/ compact.

Comment: The accepted answer also solves the question and is a one liner... unless I'm mistaken, it can be equally compact. I don't think it's necessary to have a separate `-` and space before every flag like they have.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just

```
rm tomcat7
ln -s apache-tomcat-7.0.21 tomcat7
```

?

This will not touch the old directory apache-tomcat-7.0.19 but just delete the old link. Then ln can create the new one.

Comment: Thanks! I did this currently in my script, but I think it's unlike `cp -f`/`mv -f` which use single command to do overwrite operation, so I'm looking for the *single command solution*.